# How do you override custom blockAccess() methods for blocks added with Page Manager?

Tags: 8, blocks

I've created a custom block with all its methods like `blockAccess()` etc. I would like to override one of those in another module.

In my project I have used [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager), means I think I can't call `hook_block_access()` because blocks added with Page Manager don't get into this hook.

Answer (score 0):

Your other module can implement [hook_block_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.5.x).

The example code in Drupal core looks like this:

```
function hook_block_access(\Drupal\block\Entity\Block $block, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {

  // Example code that would prevent displaying the 'Powered by Drupal' block in
  // a region different than the footer.
  if ($operation == 'view' && $block
    ->getPluginId() == 'system_powered_by_block') {
    return AccessResult::forbiddenIf($block
      ->getRegion() != 'footer')
      ->addCacheableDependency($block);
  }

  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Since it's a hook, you would have to replace the word "hook" in the function name with the machine name of your module, and place this function in the .module file.

Comment: it doesnt work with blocks added with page manager

Comment: In that case, you should have added more information to your initial question.

Comment: Can this be handled via an EventSubscriber?